# extend the product importer [magento]

Tags: magento

We have this module for importing products in our project, but the thing is that I am new in here and I have never worked with importers. I have been given a task to extend this Importer class so it adds some more stuff to a product. I also have an XML file from which I have to take only some things, that has to be imported (only some nodes and their values).

So, by extending the Importer, it's meant that I have to write new functions to the class, that will do the work (and then call this from a script, but that is not important now).

My question is - how the hell is this done?! I see there should be used arrays, but I am lost in how to abuse the API in order to search through the XML, match some nodes, extract their values and then how is this passed so it gets imported in the store?
If somebody can give me a simple step tour explanation of what has to be done in this new function - it will be great!

I cannot provide code samples, because I have nothing, and when I search for some tutorials about product importers - I get only results about buying importer modules...

Comment: Have a look to this link http://www.insanityinside.net/2013/09/magento-dataflow-batch-exports-and.html  probably your module have to be call in import/export advanced profile